# List with primitive array versus List with Object array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have the below piece of code for swapping.

```
public static <E> void swap(List<E> list, int i, int j){
        E temp = list.get(i);
        list.set(i, list.get(j));
        list.set(j, temp);
}
```

Now when I use List backed by Integer array like below

```
Integer[] ar = new Integer[]{1,2};      
swap(Arrays.asList(ar),1,0);
```

It works fine and gives output as `[2,1]`
But I use List backed by int array like below

```
int[] ar = new int[]{1,2};
swap(Arrays.asList(ar),1,0);
```

It hrows ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. I don't understand why this is happening. List should treat int element as object only. Little help please.

Comment: Adding some garbage text to meet the minimum requirements for posting a question is ridiculous.

Comment: Thanks Aniket. Love your reply :)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I'm actually surprised the garbage text was even needed.  Certainly, I have seen shorter questions today, so it can't be a length requirement alone.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think it's code vs text ratio which is considered. Never really read about it though.

Comment: If it's the ratio of text to code, @UtpalKumar should have been fine if he hadn't included most of his questions inside of the code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is happening.  Your current code is actually creating a `List<Object>`, which happens to contain just a single `int[]`, not a list of actual integers:

```
int[] ar = new int[]{1,2};
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(ar);
```

The reason for the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception is that the list you pass in to the `swap` method has only one entry, at index zero.

In any case, it is not possible to use `Arrays.asList` to directly convert an array of primitives to a list of some boxed type.  The first version of your code is correct, and is what you should be using:

```
Integer[] ar = new Integer[] {1, 2};
swap(Arrays.asList(ar), 1, 0);
```

Comment: In both cases i.e primitive and Wrapper object array, i am passing only Array object reference to swap method, where it is viewed as List and being referred by a list object. I still don't get how i am passing a single int[]. Is it something to do with internal structure of both the arrays.

Comment: That's the thing, `viewed as List` doesn't mean what you think it does.  The way you are calling `Arrays.asList` without specifying a type means that it defaults to `List<Object>`, with one entry for the primitive array.  It doesn't "know" that you want a list of integers.

Comment: I guess you are right, when i do this "int[] ar1 = new int[]{1,2}; System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ar1).size());" it returns 1.